# How to create template file for specific node?

Tags: theming

As I asked above is it possible to create template file for specific node id.
I now we can create template file for content type, but not clear for node id.

E.g. Suppose there are 10 Articles in website, each has node id from 1-10.
Now question is I want to create template file for node id 3. When user visit article node id 4, then user will see different page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 7, you can use node--[node-id].tpl.php for theming specific nodes. In your case, you can use node--3.tpl.php.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, I have one more query regarding this. Suppose instead of node id, if there is  alias in url and we don't know the node id then how we can create template in this condition.